# htaccess: IP address as GET param rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What I am trying to do is to pass an IP address as a GET param ($s) to search.php like this:
`www.example.com/search.php?p=2&s=192.168.1.1`

But instead of the "GET" data in the URL, I want the URL to look like:
`www.example.com/search/192_168_1_1.html`

`/search/` comes from `p=2` and
`192_168_1_1.html` comes from `s=192.168.1.1`

The IP addresses will vary.

It's a bit of a specific problem and it seems I can't ask Google a proper question to get the right results. Any help with that?

The part where I need to pass the `p` param is easy:
`RewriteRule ^test/$ /search.php?p=1`

But the part with the IP address gives me a headache. My URL rewrite knowledge is minimal.

Am I at least moving in the right direction with the following rule?
`RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]{3}_0-9]{3}_0-9]{3}_0-9]{3})/$ /search.php?s=$1`

Little workaround:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*).html$ /search.php?s=$1
```

It will pass the `192_168_1_1` as a param. I gues I will have to replace _ with . in php code. Unless someone will save me with better solution :)

Comment: can you show us what you have *tried so far*?

Comment: if its only cosmetic, theres js for that

Comment: It's  not just cosmetic. Link like that will be more google friendly and etc.

Comment: The part where I need to pass p param is easy. RewriteRule ^test/$ /search.php?p=1 But the part with IP gives me headache. My url rewrite knowledge is minimal.

Comment: You should post your current code as an edit of your answer and not as a comment.